# getting a variable from a public scope to connect database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php  
$settings['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$settings['username'] = 'root';
$settings['password'] = 'root';
$settings['database'] = 'band';
$settings['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

/**
* DATABASE
*/
class database
{
 protected $settings;
 function __construct()
 {

 }

 function connect() 
    {
  $this->start = new PDO(
  $this->settings['dbdriver'] . ':host='. 
  $this->settings['hostname'] . ';dbname='. 
  $this->settings['database'],
  $this->settings['username'],
  $this->settings['password'],
  array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

  $this->start->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    }
}
?>
```

ok im still a student so today im learning about scope and connections database
the question is how can i put the $settings out of the class in to the protected $settings in class ?

Comment: Why are you making a PDO wrapper? If its for learning purposes ignore silly ol' me.

Comment: well for like     function fetch($sql, $data = array()) 
    {
        $fetch = $this->start->prepare($sql);
        $fetch->execute($data);
        
        return $fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

Comment: :D. learning making a silly newbie wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already on the right path in the code you show: Don't use public (global) scope at all - it's not regarded good practice in OOP to rely on global variables, because it breaks encapsulation. Instead, inject the settings into the object when initializing it.

You could add a constructor to do that:

```
function __construct($settings)
 {
   $this->settings = $settings;
 }
```

and then initialize the class like so:

```
 $database= new database($settings);
```

or like so, to prevent a variable with sensitive data floating around:

```
 $database= new database(array('hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
                  'username' => 'root',
                  'password' => 'root',
                  'database' => 'band',
                  'dbdriver' => 'mysql'));
```

As a side note, in production use, consider deleting the `password` variable from the array after connecting, for security. It's nothing essential but a nice additional thing to do.

Comment: Does it really do any good to unset the password variable? As soon as an attacker gathers code-execution access to your application unseting the password won't help any more. He may fire queries even without the password.

Comment: @nikic this is more for situations when a full variable dump is done from within the script (e.g. when a production app accidentally runs with development error reporting settings). I've seen frameworks doing a `var_dump` on errors in verbose mode. It's not massively essential but can't hurt either

Comment: how do i delete the password after connection ?

Comment: @Adam `unset($this->settings["password"]);`

Answer (score 1):

Either pass the `$settings` as function argument, import it to current scope using `global` or access via `$GLOBALS`.

Pass as argument:

```
public function __construct(array $settings) {
    $this->settings = $settings;
}
```

Import using `global`:

```
public function __construct() {
    global $settings;
    $this->settings = $settings;
}
```

Use `$GLOBALS`:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->settings = $GLOBALS['settings'];
}
```

I would choose the pass as arg variant. The other versions are only dirty hacks (imho).

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to either look in a configuration file (a XML file for example) for the configuration, or have the connect() method (or your constructor) called with the desired parameters.